# MUI IconButton not showing on the screen (screen size < 1024), when screen size >= 1024, it works

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I'm using MUI, Tailwind and Swiper together, here is my ArrowButton

```
const ArrowButtons: React.FC<IArrowButtonsProps> = ({ swiperInstance }) => {
  const goPrev = () => {
    if (swiperInstance) swiperInstance.slidePrev();
  };

  const goNext = () => {
    if (swiperInstance) swiperInstance.slideNext();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={clsxm(
          'btn-left',
          'absolute top-[42%] left-[2%] xl:left-[14.5%] z-50',
          'bg-white opacity-[.87]',
          'w-[60px] h-[60px] rounded-full',
          'border-solid border-green-accent border',
        )}
      >
        <IconButton
          className="custom-swiper-button-prev-2 w-full h-full text-green-accent"
          aria-label="backward"
          onClick={goPrev}
        >
          <ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>

      <div
        className={clsxm(
          'btn-right',
          'absolute top-[42%] right-[2%] xl:right-[14.5%] z-50',
          'bg-white opacity-[.87]',
          'w-[60px] h-[60px] rounded-full',
          'border-solid border-green-accent border',
        )}
      >
        <IconButton
          className="custom-swiper-button-next-2 w-full h-full text-green-accent"
          aria-label="forward"
          onClick={goNext}
        >
          <ArrowForwardIosRoundedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And I conditonal render the Button in three size of screen, like this

```
{is2Xl ? (... 
   <ArrowButtons swiperInstance={swiperInstances[0]} />
  ) ? isXl (...
    <ArrowButtons swiperInstance={swiperInstances[1]} />
    ) : (...
      <ArrowButtons swiperInstance={swiperInstances[2]} />
      )
```

My problem is when it comes to the last condition(screen size<= 1024), I can see the `div` wrapped `<IconButton />`, but the `<IconButton />` is not showing, and I open my console, I see it's gray

[image: gray IconButton]

In the screen:

[image: In the screen]

And it works on bigger screen, what's happened?

[image: bigger screen]

The IconButton can not show on the screen size below 1024px